# With sqlalchemy one() function can more than one row be returned from the database engine?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, hana

From the documentation:

> Return exactly one result or raise an exception.

This is from the function call. What I am wondering is that if the database engine is running somewhere else with communication via tcp (for example), can the machine running the SQLAlchemy application ever receive more than one result?

I would assume this would be independent of DB but if this isn't the case my question is for hana DB.

Comment: The DBMS being local or remote makes no difference. Yes, your query can result in 0..* results, but `one()` will return only 1 result, or raise an exception in case of 0, or 2 or more results.

Comment: Yes but where exactly can the query result of 0..* results occur? On the local machine running sqlalchemy and the hana client or on the remote machine running the DBMS.  If the query results (prior to one) will result in huge memory usage will this be on the local or remote machine?

Comment: I think my question has been misunderstood, I'm not asking if the DB being local or remote makes a difference to what One returns.

Comment: Ah, ok so you're interested in whether or not the entire result set is fetched first?

Comment: Yes, whether it's fetched to the local machine.

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py#L550 it looks like it is using a form of "fetchone", but your driver might still be buffering the raw results client side, if your driver+DBMS combination does not support server side cursors.

Comment: Is it also possible if the function doesn't throw an exception (i.e. only one is returned) that multiple results are still buffered client side?

Comment: PS if you leave an answer I will accept it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behind the scenes `Query.one()` [uses a "fetch one" approach](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py#L556), but that is not the whole story. Whether or not your client first buffers the entire query result depends on your driver in use and the DBMS – for example if it supports server side cursors or not.

Also, SQLAlchemy `Query` deduplicates single ORM entity results, such as

```
session.query(MyModel).one()
```

In order to do that it has to keep on reading the result set until it either finds a non-unique result, in which case it raises an exception, or there are no more results. One might wonder when could there even be such duplicates, and an answer to that is "when using joins":

```
session.query(MyModel).join(MyModelChild).one()
```

The end result is that it has to read the entire result set, or up to first non-unique result, if using the ORM and the `Query` API, or [`Result.scalar_one()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Result.scalar_one) in the 2.0 style API.

Answer (score 3):

> can the machine running the sqlalchemy application ever receive more than one result?

Yes. Confirmed with `mysql+mysqlclient`.

Example data:

```py
class Message(Base):
    __tablename__ = "message"
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = sa.Column(sa.String(50), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Message(id={self.id}, data='{self.data}')>"


Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with sa.orm.Session(engine, future=False) as session:
    session.add_all([Message(data="Alfa"), Message(data="Bravo")])
    session.commit()
```

Test query:

```py
with sa.orm.Session(engine) as session:
    result = session.query(Message).one()
```

Wireshark packet:

```
0000   40 2c f4 34 c0 d3 00 21 70 75 83 c1 08 00 45 00   @,.4...!pu....E.
0010   00 ca 2d ec 40 00 3f 06 8a 77 c0 a8 00 c7 c0 a8   ..-.@.?..w......
0020   00 b3 0c ea ef 75 ab 6d 1c 34 2a ae cc 7b 50 18   .....u.m.4*..{P.
0030   01 f5 91 aa 00 00 01 00 00 01 02 34 00 00 02 03   ...........4....
0040   64 65 66 04 74 65 73 74 07 6d 65 73 73 61 67 65   def.test.message
0050   07 6d 65 73 73 61 67 65 0a 6d 65 73 73 61 67 65   .message.message
0060   5f 69 64 02 69 64 0c 3f 00 0b 00 00 00 03 03 42   _id.id.?.......B
0070   00 00 00 38 00 00 03 03 64 65 66 04 74 65 73 74   ...8....def.test
0080   07 6d 65 73 73 61 67 65 07 6d 65 73 73 61 67 65   .message.message
0090   0c 6d 65 73 73 61 67 65 5f 64 61 74 61 04 64 61   .message_data.da
00a0   74 61 0c ff 00 c8 00 00 00 fd 01 10 00 00 00 05   ta..............
00b0   00 00 04 fe 00 00 21 00 07 00 00 05 01 31 04 41   ......!......1.A
00c0   6c 66 61 08 00 00 06 01 32 05 42 72 61 76 6f 05   lfa.....2.Bravo.
00d0   00 00 07 fe 00 00 21 00                           ......!.
```

Notice that both rows are returned in the same packet. Therefore in this case even if SQLAlchemy uses `.fetchone()` the database may return multiple rows (as explained in [Ilja's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68132464/2144390): the database may not be configured — or be able — to only return one row at a time).

So, at least for a default MySQL configuration, `.one()` does not limit the number of rows/objects returned, it only verifies that we received exactly one of them. That's why we get the exception

> sqlalchemy.exc.MultipleResultsFound: Multiple rows were found when exactly one was required